# Setting up project in OpenCV in XCode4

Tags: xcode, opencv

I am a new OpenCV and XCode user and I have looked on the internet for a tutorial to setup a sample project in XCode 4 using OpenCV and couldnt find any. Does someone know of one?

Comment: hey user743966 did you get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/foipmm7q9n8aaht/How%20to%20get%20OpenCV%20working%20under%20Mac%20OS%20X%20Lion%20with%20XCode%204.1%20%C2%AB%20Salem%27s%20Log.pdf

check out the above link.It worked for me.Download the pdf.I'm seeing some weird fonts in the program from my browser.

NOTE:  #include&  . Don't just use this header directly.Cross check where the following header 'opencv.hpp' is stored and include it.